# Button text "&gt;" and "&lt;" is not converting to ">" and "<" in xamarin forms

Tags: string, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, string-conversion

I just need to display ">" and "<" as button text so I just used &gt with a semicolon and &lt with semicolon but in the UI it is showing the text instead of "<" and ">". But it is working fine in Xaml not in code behind c# file.

Please find the code

```
        CustomButton moveToNewCheckButton = new CustomButton
        {
            Text = "&gt;",
            Style = (Style) Application.Current.Resources["MoveButtonStyle"],
            AutomationId = "MoveToNewCheckButton"
        };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use

```
Text = ">",
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the @Jason answer, you also can use `WebUtility.HtmlDecode` method. e.g. in case you want to use the same string in both Xaml and C#.

```cs
using System.Net;

Text = WebUtility.HtmlDecode("&gt;");
```